# How can I enable SSI on HTML pages on GoDaddy (Windows hosting)?

Tags: godaddy, server-side-includes

I wish to enable SSI's (server-side includes) on my HTML pages on GoDaddy.

I want lines like this to be processed properly:

```
<!--#include virtual="/include/header.html"-->
```

Is this possible and how can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

Spoke with GoDaddy support.

They do support SSI, but only with '.shtml' files.

No configuration is necessary, simply make sure the files containing the SSI's have a '.shtml' extension.

Answer (score 1):

Not true. I've got this working on two different shared hosting accounts with GoDaddy using this .htaccess:

```
AddType text/html .shtml .shtm .htm .html 
AddHandler server-parsed .shtml .shtm .htm .html
```

However, from searching around, it looks like they claim you no longer need to edit your .htaccess.

Comment: "No longer true" might be a nicer approach when responding to a two year old answer.